# NodeJS: Promise won't catch thrown exceptions

Tags: node.js, error-handling, promise

I have a code like this (simplified):

```
getStreamFor(path) {
    // both, remote and local, return a Promise
    if(...) { return getRemoteFileStream(path); }
    else { return getLocalFileStream(path); }
}

getRemoteFileStream(path) {
    // should throw in my case (MyError)
    const validPath = validatePath(path); 
    return readStreamIfValid(validPath);
}
```

and in the test case:

```
it('should throw MyError', () => {
    return getStreamFor(path)
        .then(() => {})
        .catch(error => expect(error).to.be.instanceOf(MyError));
});
```

The problem is, that when the `validatePath(path)` Method throws (due to invalid path), nothing get caught in the test case promise. The output in my terminal / console is a regular exception as if it was uncaught.

Does anybody have an idea, why the the Promise wouldn't recognize the throw? How can I fix it without probably surrounding the call in the test case with another "try catch" (since the promise should do that for me)?

Maybe there is a general best practise how to structure Promises in order to avoid error swallowings like these?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You say that "*both, remote and local, return a Promise*" but then you say that `getRemoteFileStream` "*should throw*". That's not returning a promise.

Comment: Yeah, It throws an exception, that I was expecting to be handled and forwarded by the surrounding promise as "rejected".

Comment: Well it would be, the problem is just that there is no promise that *surrounds* the call in your code :-) You could easily introduce one though by making it an `async function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `validatePath()` is not part of the promise chain returned by `getRemoteFileStream()`

One possible solution is the following:

```
getRemoteFileStream(path) {
    return Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => validatePath(path))
        .then(validPath => readStreamIfValid(validPath));
}
```

An exception thrown by `validatePath()` would now be handled in the Promise's catch handler.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I've been looking for! One little question, though: When there is more than one variable from the first `then`-part, that is needed in the second `then`-part - is there a good way to handle this, too?

Comment: Simpler: `Promise.resolve(path).then(validatePath).then(readStreamIfValid)`

Comment: @jlang What do you mean by "more than one variable"? A function can only return a single value.